# absolute persistent cohomology bar codes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

Can anyone explain the persistent absolute cohomology bar codes? how are the indices defined in absolute persistent cohomology?

For example, [image]

corresponds to the filtration $X_1 \subset ... \subset X_6$

Recall we have the persistent module:
$H^*(X_1) \leftarrow ... \leftarrow H^*(X_{5}) \leftarrow H^*(X_6)$

there should thus be absolute cohomology barcodes: 
$\{[1,\infty)_0, [2,3)_0, [4,5)_1, [6,\infty)_2\}$ where the subscript refers to dimension of the generating cocycle.

How do we explain the barcodes for this example?

Comment: Do you understand why those are the barcodes for the absolute homology? It's then a theorem that these barcodes agree. I guess I don't totally understand what you're asking.

Comment: You can write out the betti numbers of the 0,1,2-th homology of each complex in the filtration to check the barcodes for absolute homology. The issue is that I don't understand the result of the theorem. It looks like the indices are backwards or something.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a barcode of the form $[a,b)_n$ establishes that there is an $n$-cocycle with non-trivial cohomology class arising at time $a$ that persists up to time $b$.

For instance, the barcode $[2,3)_0$ corresponds to the $0$-cocycle associated to the point $2$. Note that $H^0(X_2)=\langle 1,2\rangle \simeq \Bbb{Z}^2$, where $1$ and $2$ denote the corresponding $0$-cocycles. The cochain $2$ is no longer a cocyle in $H^2(X_3)$, since its differential is not zero.

Comment: I do not understand. (let $\sigma_i^*$ be the dual cochain associated with the basis chain $\sigma_i$). How is cochain $\sigma_2^*$ a cocycle on $X_3$? isn't the coboundary of cochain $\sigma_2^*$ the cochain $\sigma_3^*$? $\delta$($\sigma_2^*$)= $\sigma_3^*$ $\neq$ 0?

Comment: You are right - editing accordingly.

Comment: It appears that the diagram was drawn with persistent _homology_ rather than cohomology in mind (I was thinking about homology in my original answer as well). I now see why you're confused about the intervals been backwards - they are not if you think about it homologically, since the homology class of the point 2 ceases to be a non-trivial class at step 3, being homologous to 1.